# Empty/Invalid token in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have a custom authenticator that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface;`
.

The problem I have is that I have a `$token->getCredentials()` that seems to return `null`
from the function that token is being passed to below. So I can't check the token for a username or password against my custom authenticator.

```
public function authenticateToken(
    TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    ...
}
```

What can I start to check in order to know why my token is empty?

Edit: I think I'm getting closer to the problem:

```
public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
```

Where is `createToken` getting `$username, $password` from?

Comment: Do you authenticate your user via login form?

Comment: Yes, I do. Does it matter if it's a custom type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a different question that I thought was related to this and it was so here's the answer:

[Symfony2, forms, username_parameter and firewall parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324361/symfony2-forms-username-parameter-and-firewall-parameters)

From the security.yml parameters the `user_parameter`, `password_parameter` gets picked up for the token values. And therefore not invalid or null anymore when set.

Answer (score 1):

did you set up a firewall allowing this authentication in your app/config/config.yml ?

Comment: Yes, I can log in with static credentials that are checked against my custom authenticator just fine. If I can just get the token that would pretty much make the whole thing work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @showdev I'm going to be the devil's advocate and say it's an answer in the wrong form when he probably actually meant: "Make sure you setup a firewall with this authentication under app/config/config.yml". Which sounds like a  pretty reasonable answer to me.

Comment: @Tek If this worked for you, please approve the answer and/or upvote.